# C++ auto specifier and smart pointers

Tags: c++

After I have read a few posts on the use of `auto` specifier I am a bit confused about its proper use with smart pointers.

In the case when I am getting a pointer to an instance of an object:

```
shared_ptr<SomeObject> ptr = parent.getSomeObject();
```

Should I use:

```
1. auto
2. auto&
3. auto&&
```

And then

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<member>> members;
for (auto member : members)  // auto, auto& or auto&&
{
    ....
}
```

I suppose the same rule will apply to weak_ptr, unique_ptr...

Comment: For your first question it really depends.  What does `getSomeObject`?  Do you want the call site to share in the ownership or are you okay with a reference?

Comment: I haven't thought about that. I actually want to know about all the possible use cases. Anyway in the case I have in mind I only need a reference.